# How to reassign security groups of an instance in step functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-step-functions, aws-security-group, aws-auto-scaling

I am running a step functions workflow but there is no predefined state to reassign security group to a specific instance using the instance id. I already have 2 security groups created (default and the one i want to assign)

What are the ways this can be done?

Tried running it as a task with the following api parameters

```
{
  "command": [
    "aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id $instance_id --groups $security_group_id"
  ]
}
```

Comment: what is the error message >?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra 
The resource provided arn:aws:states:::aws:runShellScript is not recognized. The value is not a valid resource ARN, or the resource is not available in this region. (at /States/ReassignSecurityGroup/Resource)

Comment: what if you try to hardcore instance if and security group id just to test it out whether command is running or not?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for the resource `arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:ec2:modifyInstanceAttribute`. This uses [AWS SDK Service Integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/supported-services-awssdk.html) to call the [EC2 API Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyInstanceAttribute.html).

To make it easier to find the supported service integrations for Step Functions, I suggest using [Step Functions Workflow Studio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/workflow-studio.html). It makes it really easy to search for available API actions and to build your workflows.

[image]

And if you'd like to learn more about AWS SDK Service Integrations, check out the module in [the Step Functions Workshop](https://catalog.workshops.aws/stepfunctions/en-US/module-9).